# how to bind events to data loaded via ajax and still work

Tags: jquery

I have implemented ajax tabs, and in 1 ajax tab I load a calendar which changes the month and year with ajax. The problem I am having is binding events for the loaded content.

here is an example of code I am using:

```js
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'main/ajaxjson/load_course_details',
     data: {page : which},
     success: function(home){       
            $('#ajax-content ').hide();
            $('#ajax-content').empty().append(home);
            $('#ajax-content').fadeIn();               
     }
 })
```

with this code I load the tabs, i generate the entire html and append it to the ajax-content div.
after this I bind the events to use for the new content like this:

```
('body').on('click', 'a.next-month', function(){
     // code here })
```

But the problem with this is it loses data after each click..i want to have all the data loaded and perform ajax requests on the new data with ease.

Answer (score 0):

use a object to store already made ajax calls:

```
var whichTree = {};

var handler = function(home){  
    whichTree[which] = home;     
    $('#ajax-content ').hide();
    $('#ajax-content').empty().append(home);
    $('#ajax-content').fadeIn();               
};

if ( whichTree[which] ) {
    handler(whichTree[which]);
}
else { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'main/ajaxjson/load_course_details',
        data: {page : which},
        success: handler
    });
}
```

Comment: and how do i call it again? i need to call it every time i make a new action?